# How to remove loader mask in iframe at the time of loading the url

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, extjs4.2

i want to hide the default loader mask for the iframe at the time of loading the url

```
{
                    xtype: 'uxiframe',
                     listeners: {
                        afterrender: function () {
                                     this.load('https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
                        }
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items : [{
    xtype : "component",
    autoEl : {
        tag : "iframe",
        src : ...
    },
    listeners: {
        load: {
            element: 'el',
            fn: function () {
                this.parent().unmask();
            }
        },
        render: function () {
            this.up('panel').body.mask("Loading...");
        }
    }

}]
```